# Indentation Error

Tags: python, methods, max, indentation, function

I'm trying to define a method similar to the method max but I get an error for an expected indentation. I'm not exactly sure what is wrong with the code... I need help solving this.

```
def biggest(a,b,c):
    def bigger(a,b):
        if a > b:
            output = a
        else:
            output = b
        if output > c:
            return output
        else:
            return c
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `max`?

Comment: Why have you nested two `def`s? The second one is unnecessary.

Comment: There's no indentation error in what you gave.

Comment: This should instead be a duplicate of [I'm getting an IndentationError (or a TabError). How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mixed up tabs and spaces. Use `python -tt` to verify.