# Can I call several Python functions when an if statement is true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am using Python 3.6.

I am trying to write some code that contains a number of if statements.

I would like to create an if statement, that when 'true', will call two (or more functions) but I am having trouble doing this...

For example:

```
if x == 1: function_1()
```

works as expected, but

```
if x == 1: function_1(), function_2()
```

does not work, I get an 'object is not callable' error for function_2.

If I try:

```
if x == 1: function_1()
   function_2()
```

I get an unexpected indent error... if I try:

```
if x == 1: function_1()
function_2()
```

Pycharm tells me that the function_2() statement has no effect and only function_1() is called.

I am left scratching my head on how this can be done as its seems logical to expect that I would be able to 'do' more than one thing at the end of an if statement.

What can I try next?

Comment: Put both on new lines

Comment: You may want to review a tutorial on python indentation.

Comment: Just put the two function calls on separate lines.

Comment: @TemporalWolf You mean... like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it/45621723?noredirect=1#comment78240595_45621723) ;-)

Comment: The version with the comma should have worked (though it's not the natural way to do what you want). It sounds like your `function_2` may not be what you expect it to be. Perhaps you have a typo?

Comment: Thanks all - I think I may have been a bit of a dummy :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def function_1():
    print("function 1")


def function_2():
    print("function 2")


foo = True


if foo:
    function_1()
    function_2()
```

Comment: Thank you - I think I may have been a bit of a dummy with my function naming, but your post is still useful,

Comment: There's almost never a good reason to test `foo is True`. Just test `foo`.

Comment: No worries. Indentation is important, I think it's best to keep things clear and give each function call it's own line. Reading more code written by other people will help you to internalize how to structure things.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for your comment, please can you elaborate on what you mean as I am a little unclear...

Comment: @Blckknght you're correct, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @rug3y thanks for that - I see what Blckknght meant now!

Answer (score 2):

Python uses indentation level to organize blocks instead of using curly braces like C or Java.

```
if x == 1:
    function_1()
    function_2()
```

This will call both functions.