# Python Error self.reader.next()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am receiving an error and don't know how to fix it. The error is show below along with the program. I am a beginner to programming so everything is new to me. My program's goal is to read information based of the year and location and print out the corresponding information into `PSSE`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/RoszkowskiM/Desktop/dictreader.py", line 75, in <module>
for row in reader:
File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 103, in next
self.fieldnames
File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 90, in fieldnames
self._fieldnames = self.reader.next()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

_

```
import csv
LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE = 'C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Desktop\Data_2017.csv'
with open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE) as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
mydict = {}
for row in reader:
    Year=row['Year']
    Busnum=row['Busnum']
    Area=row['Area']
    Power=row['Power']
    TLA=row['TLA']
    Location=row['Location']
    Yearlink=row['Yearlink']
    From=row['From']
    To=row['To']
    Max=row['Max']
    Min=row['Min']

year = raw_input("Please Select Year of Study: ")
print("\n")

commands = ["Millwood-Buchanan", "Astoria-East-Corona", "Bronx", "DUNWOODIE-North-Sherman_Creek",
        "Vernon", "Greenwood-StatenIsland","West_49th","East_13th","Staten_Island","East_River",
        "East_View","DUNWOODIE-SOUTH","Corona-Jamaica","Astoria-East-Corona-Jamaica",
        "Astoria-West-Queensbridge-Vernon","Astoria-West-Queensbridge"]
max_columns = 50

for index, commands in enumerate(commands):
    stars_amount = max(max_columns - len(commands), 0)
    row = "# {} {}({})".format(commands, "." * stars_amount, index + 1)
    print(row)

location=raw_input(" \n The list above show the TLA Pockets as well as the ID numbers assigned to them ()\n\n Please enter the ID #: ")
print("\n")


if year in Year and location in Location:  
   mydict=(Busnum,Area,Power)

print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year and the new LOAD TOTAL: ")
print("\n")

#Busnum, busname,scaled_power read from excel sheet matching year and location
for Busnum,Area,Power in mydict:
    Power= float(scaled_power)
    Busnum = int(busnum)
    print('Bus #: %d\t' % Busnum ,'Area Station: %s\t'% Area,'New Load Total: %d MW\t' % Power)


    #API for changing and scaling generation of loads
    #psspy.bsys(1,0,[0.0,0.0],0,[],1,[Busnum],0,[],0,[])
    #psspy.scal_2(1,0,1,[0,0,0,0,0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
    #psspy.scal_2(0,1,2,[0,1,0,1,0],[Power,0.0,0,-.0,0.0,-.0,0])

    #print("\n")
```

else:
        exit

Comment: correct your indentation. It is really confusing

Comment: Indentation appears to be the issue. csvfile is only open in the with statement code block. Indent all after the with statement and it should work.

Comment: fixed that. Also the code is not outputting anything. Is there something wrong with my if statement?

Comment: If you need help fixing the indentation, please take a look at [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

when you used `with` the file only stays open as long as your in scope, when `for row in reader:` is indented incorrectly your file gets closed, i tested below and get to `please select year of study:`

```
import csv
LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE = 'C:\\Users\\Dirty-Santa\\Desktop\\blah.csv'
with open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    mydict = {}
    for row in reader:
        Year=row['Year']
        Busnum=row['Busnum']
        Area=row['Area']
        Power=row['Power']
        TLA=row['TLA']
        Location=row['Location']
        Yearlink=row['Yearlink']
        From=row['From']
        To=row['To']
        Max=row['Max']
        Min=row['Min']

year = raw_input("Please Select Year of Study: ")
print("\n")

commands = ["Millwood-Buchanan", "Astoria-East-Corona", "Bronx", "DUNWOODIE-North-Sherman_Creek",
        "Vernon", "Greenwood-StatenIsland","West_49th","East_13th","Staten_Island","East_River",
        "East_View","DUNWOODIE-SOUTH","Corona-Jamaica","Astoria-East-Corona-Jamaica",
        "Astoria-West-Queensbridge-Vernon","Astoria-West-Queensbridge"]
max_columns = 50

for index, commands in enumerate(commands):
    stars_amount = max(max_columns - len(commands), 0)
    row = "# {} {}({})".format(commands, "." * stars_amount, index + 1)
    print(row)

location=raw_input(" \n The list above show the TLA Pockets as well as the ID numbers assigned to them ()\n\n Please enter the ID #: ")
print("\n")


if year in Year and location in Location:
   mydict=(Busnum,Area,Power)

print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year and the new LOAD TOTAL: ")
print("\n")

#Busnum, busname,scaled_power read from excel sheet matching year and location
for Busnum,Area,Power in mydict:
    Power= float(scaled_power)
    Busnum = int(busnum)
    print('Bus #: %d\t' % Busnum ,'Area Station: %s\t'% Area,'New Load Total: %d MW\t' % Power)


    #API for changing and scaling generation of loads
    #psspy.bsys(1,0,[0.0,0.0],0,[],1,[Busnum],0,[],0,[])
    #psspy.scal_2(1,0,1,[0,0,0,0,0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
    #psspy.scal_2(0,1,2,[0,1,0,1,0],[Power,0.0,0,-.0,0.0,-.0,0])

    #print("\n")
```