# Converting Data Type in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data Frame with 15 columns suppose out of which i want only 6.
I am performing aggregate and then group by but it is throwing error.

```
def my_compute_function(my_input):

    df=pd.DataFrame(my_input)
    df2=df[(df['D'] == "Validated")]
    df2[['A','E','F']]=df2[['A','E','F']].apply(pd.to_numeric) 
    df3=df2[['A','B','C','D','E','F']].groupby(['B','C','D']).agg({'A': 
   'max','E': 'max','F': 'max'}).reset_index()

return df3
```

So i want only 6 columns A,B,C,D,E,F.
When i am adding this line

```py
df2[['A','E','F']]=df2[['A','E','F']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

it is throwing error that

> ValueError: can not infer schema from empty dataset.

Comment: Are you getting an actual indentation error or another error? Please [edit] your post to include the *full error*

Comment: There is no reason this should give an indent error.

Comment: IndentationError: Unexpected Indent. I also checked the spaces its fine,  and when i am removing this line my code is working fine.

Comment: See this post for more guidance https://stackoverflow.com/a/45621723/2336654

Comment: please check the edited question. Earlier i was getting indentation error but when i used df3 then i am getting the above error.

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

This will break

```
# Ignore this comment, I needed SO to show a blank
# line followed by code indented by a space

 df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can copy whitespaces from working code before problematic line:

```
#some code before, copy whitespaces from starts of line to first letter
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
^^^^copy here

    df[['A','B','C']]=df[['A','B','C']].apply(pd.to_numeric)  
^^^^paste here
```

Comment: still same error IndentationError: Unexpected Indent.

Comment: when i am assigning this Data Frame to another Data Frame then my code is executing fine but then it is giving error - cannot infer to an empty dataset.

Comment: Is possible see your code? And if possible, the best is send me your file to my email (in my profile) for check this problematic line. Without it is hard find problem connected with indent error. thanks.