# Discord Bot Indentation error: Unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, bots, discord

This line is part of a simple Discord bot python script, but that's not important. It keeps saying "Indentation Error: Unindent does not match any outer indentation level" I discovered how to fix the other Indentation error with tabs and spaces, but I still don't know why this error constantly occurs... Here's the line of code:

```
async def cmd_clean(self, message, channel, server, author, search_range=50):        

    try:
        float(search_range)  # lazy check
        search_range = min(int(search_range), 1000)
    except:
        return Response("enter a number.  NUMBER.  That means digits.  `15`.  Etc.", reply=True, delete_after=8)
```

- I'm somewhat new to python.
- That line is part of a cleaning command that will clear the bot's previous messages.

Comment: The error precisely tells you what's wrong: when you unindented your code, it did not match another indentation level. Besides, a single line of code cannot raise an indentation error. Indentation is relative, so at least two lines are needed.

Comment: Press `Ctrl+A` and then press `Shift+Tab` and try to re-Indent whole code.

Comment: Oh thanks. I'll try that. :)

Comment: Wait let me post the second line

Comment: Um I got this code from an open source website

Comment: @AustinWang Please append this to your original post by clicking `edit`. Format it as in your code. There is no way an indentation error could be found if all the code is on a single line and not indented as in the original code, since it's an error due to **formatting**.

Comment: Sorry that one was the wrong one

Comment: I did that. what should I do next?

Comment: Check if you have mixed tabs and spaces for indentation.

Comment: It keeps saying Indentation error on my computer for no reason. ok

Comment: @AustinWang are you sure `async` is written before `def`

Comment: Your code runs perfectly for me. The problem certainly lies in your file itself.

Comment: @AnuragMisra Yes.

Comment: You may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it to helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
def cmd_clean(self, message, channel, server, author, search_range=50):
    try:
        float(search_range)  # lazy check
        search_range = min(int(search_range), 1000)
    except:
        return Response("enter a number.  NUMBER.  That means digits.  `15`.  Etc.", reply=True, delete_after=8)
```

try is code I have properly indented it, and I am sure that `async` can't be before `def`. 
If this solution don't work for you can you post your full code.?

Comment: That means it would be over 1800 lines long. I got most of the code from https://github.com/Just-Some-Bots/MusicBot/blob/master/musicbot/bot.py

Comment: ok I got it. Do one thing download  [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) and copy paste that code in pycharm. After that press `Ctrl+A` and then press `Ctrl+Alt+L`. I hope your problem will be solved