# Your code displayed no output

Tags: python, function, output

I tried to run this code:

```
def readable_timedelta(days):
    days = 20
    """Print the number of weeks and days in a number of days."""
    #to get the number of weeks we use integer division
    weeks = days // 7
    #to get the number of days that remain we use %, the modulus operator
    remainder = days % 7
    return "{ } week(s) and { } day(s)". format(weeks, remainder)
    print (readable_timedelta)
```

and I keep getting this:

> Your code displayed no output

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45621723/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call your function, for example

```
readable_timedelta(20)
```

Otherwise all you did was define a function, and as the note says there is no output from this program.

Side comment: there is no point in putting a `print` statement (or anything for that matter) after a `return` statement as no further code will execute and the function will return execution to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few minor things you need to consider.

1.You need to call your function, and since you want to print the returned value, you need to call inside the print. `print(readable_timedelta(20))`

2.There is no need of variable `days = 20` inside the function. If you do so every time your function will give the same result, that is "2 week(s) and 6 day(s)".

3.Whenever program will reach `return` statement anycode after that will never be executed, hence `print()` will never be executed. Either use `return` or `print()`.

```
#Code with return

def readable_timedelta(days):

    """Print the number of weeks and days in a number of days."""
    #to get the number of weeks we use integer division
    weeks = days // 7
    #to get the number of days that remain we use %, the modulus operator
    remainder = days % 7
    return "{ } week(s) and { } day(s)". format(weeks, remainder)


#Calling Function
print(readable_timedelta(20))
print(readable_timedelta(40))
```

If we use print inside a function definition, we can simply call the function with the required parameter.

```
#Code without return

def readable_timedelta(days):

    """Print the number of weeks and days in a number of days."""
    #to get the number of weeks we use integer division
    weeks = days // 7
    #to get the number of days that remain we use %, the modulus operator
    remainder = days % 7
    print("{ } week(s) and { } day(s)". format(weeks, remainder))


#Calling Function
readable_timedelta(20)
readable_timedelta(40)
```