# What's wrong with this little python code? And how to fix it?

Tags: python

I added an 'if else statement' but I don't know why the program is not running!! Can you please help me fix this. I'm a total beginner and this is the 1st time I'm a Python Code

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [ask].

Comment: Looks like your indentation is messed up. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it) may be of use.

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is [important in Python](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html). Remove the first space in the first line, and indent the code after `else:`, on line 8 and 10.

Comment: Thnx a lot !! Really. I didn't know this. And yesterday night I reviewed the code, again and again, searched on the web but didn't get the result. But this comment made my day. Really Thank You, Eric!!