# Python if else executing in a bad way

Tags: python, if-statement, return

I am new to python and trying to execute my code.  Below is my code.

```
   def evod(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print("The number is even")
    return"The number is odd"

print(evod(60))

Output is: 
The number is even
The number is odd
```

if I run this function it prints both lines. It should print a single one of those. Right? Why is this happening?

Comment: You need to indent your code. Specifically, the body of the `if` statement.

Comment: Indentation defines the code blocks in Python. Indent the first `print` and it will work.

Comment: You may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it) question and answer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
if c=="July":
    print("7/1/2017")
else:
    print("sorry")
```

Indentation matters in python!

Answer (score 0):

```
if c == "July":
    print ("7/1/2017")
else:
    print ("sorry")
```

Correct your indentation

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know indention matters in python.