# Expected an indented block error(Protein Sequence Count)

Tags: python

The code:

```
def find_orf_lengths(dna,frame,cutoff):
    orfs_lengths = []

    for i in range(0,len(dna),3):
        if(dna[i:i+3] == "ATG"):
            orfs_lenghts[i] += 1
            elif(dna[i:i+3] == "TGA"|"TAA"|"TAG"):
                if(orfs_lenghts[i] >= cutoff):
                    orfs_lengths.append(100)
                    elif(orfs_lenghts[i] < cutoff):
                        continue

    return orfs_lengths
```

I was working on a protein sequence project and the problem is, whatever I do I can't get past the "Expected an indented block" error which is given like this:

```
             File "lab6hw.py", line 27
               if(dna[i:i+3] == "ATG"):
            IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: You've mixed spaces and tabs, among other indentation problems.

Comment: `elif`'s should be indented the same as their associated `if`'s.

Comment: This may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put elif at same indent level as if:

```
def find_orf_lengths(dna,frame,cutoff):
    orfs_lengths = []
    for i in range(0, len(dna), 3):
        if(dna[i:i + 3] == "ATG"):
            orfs_lenghts[i] += 1
        elif(dna[i:i + 3] == "TGA" | "TAA" | "TAG"):
            if(orfs_lenghts[i] >= cutoff):
                orfs_lengths.append(100)
            elif(orfs_lenghts[i] < cutoff):
                continue

    return orfs_lengths
```

Answer (score 1):

An `elif` has to be at the same indentation level as an `if` above it. You probably meant something like this:

```
def find_orf_lengths(dna,frame,cutoff):
    orfs_lengths = []

    for i in range(0,len(dna),3):
        if(dna[i:i+3] == "ATG"):
            orfs_lenghts[i] += 1
        elif(dna[i:i+3] == "TGA"|"TAA"|"TAG"):
            if(orfs_lenghts[i] >= cutoff):
                orfs_lengths.append(100)
            elif(orfs_lenghts[i] < cutoff):
                continue

    return orfs_lengths
```

Though I can't test your code without knowing the inputs.