# If else error "IndentationError: unexpected indent"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to learn Python and I'm running the code:

```
for car in cars:
  if car == 'bmw':
      print(car.upper())
  else:
      print(car.title())
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
for car in cars:
...    if car == 'bmw':
...       print(car.upper())
...           else:
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

How can I improve the code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use backticks to format your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError (or a TabError). How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-or-a-taberror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The error message does not seem to match the code. The error message suggests the "`else`" has actually been indented seven more spaces than the "`if`", thus causing "`IndentationError: unexpected indent`". The indentation levels are not required to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

This should help I hope.

```
cars = ['audi', 'bmw']
for car in cars:
    if car == 'bmw':
        print(car.upper())
    else:
        print(car.title())
```

Also, do not mix tabs and spaces when indenting your code. This could be the reason why you're getting the error.

Answer (score -1):

As the error suggests, the problem is with the indentation of the else statement. It should be at the same indentation level as the `if` statement in the for loop.

```
if...:
    .....
else:
    .....
```