# IndentationError unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in python.

I code to receive a string and find it's most occurring character

```
userInput=input()
my_input=list(userInput)

count= {}

for num in my_input:
     count[num] = count.get(num,0)+1
    m=max(count)

print(m)
```

when i executed i receive this error

```
File "third.py", line 8
    m=max(count)
               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, these errors are in the line before what it shown in the error. And I can easily see that your `count[num]` is one space too far to the right. I think that indentation in Python is typically 4 spaces from the left margin.

Depending on your text editor, you could also fix it by deleting the spaces before the lines in the `for` loop, i.e.

```
for num in my_inputs:
count[num] = count.get(num, 0)+1
m=max(count)
```

and then pressing the `tab` key to format them.

```
for num in my_inputs:
    count[num] = count.get(num, 0)+1
    m=max(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
userInput=input()
my_input=list(userInput)

count= {}

for num in my_input:
     count[num] = count.get(num,0)+1
     ^ this is at the 5th blank space indent    
    m=max(count)
    ^ this is at the 4th space indent (the correct one)
print(m)
```

so whats happening is its throwing it off with your uneven spacing. Try to stick to 4 spaces or just 1-tab(but make sure your IDE can convert it to spaces).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i corrected it.I have one more question when i input string 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbcddddeeeeee' it gives me the output 'e' not 'a'.I'm little bit confused in it

Comment: That's because when you do `max(count)` it's taking the maximum value of the keys, not the values in the keys. In Python, 'e' is greater than 'a', so `max(count)` returns 'e'. To get the key with the maximum value, you can do `max(count, key=count.get)`, which is based on the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)