# How to fix IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, indentation

i am getting this error 
  File "ad.py", line 132
    else :
         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

what do i have to change? i am actually kinda new
thanks

```
                        print("ACCOUNT WAS BANIDA!")
                        break
                    except UserChannelsTooMuchError:
                        print('userbe many groups.')
                else :
                    ja_adicionado += 1
                    print('Already added:{}'.format(ja_adicionado))
                    continue
            else :        
                ja_adicionado += 1
                print("{} is already in the group.".format(user['name']))
                continue
        if user == users[-1]:
            print('LIST FINISHED!')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

There might be spaces mixed in with your tab. This will cause that error. Configure your editor to use space only for indentation.

Answer (score 0):

thanks about the answear, have you know to solve this error that im getting ?

SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

lines:

    `else :

        ja_adicionado += 1
        print("{} is already in the 
group.".format(user['name']))
        continue
if user == users[-1]:
    print('LIST FINISHED!')`

Answer (score 0):

It might because continue is only allowed within a for or while loop. A more recent version of python raise a syntax error when modules containing break or continue outside of a loop are imported.