# Issues when running a for loop & appending the items to a empty list in Python

Tags: python, list, function, loops, for-loop

I would like to know what am I doing wrong with my code. I'm a [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) developer & I'm learning [Python](https://www.python.org/about/) currently. I'm creating a `function` that takes a `list` as an argument, loops through it & appends a new `list` with items type `string` from the previous one. However, I'm getting this error `SyntaxError: bad input on line 4 in main.py`.

First, I would like to know what I'm doing wrong. Second, how can I fix it?

```
def filter_list(arr):
  results = list()

    for x in arr:
        if isinstance(x, str):
        results.append(x)
        print(results)

filter_list([1, 2, 3, "a", "b", 4])
```

Comment: The indentation in your example doesn't look right.

Comment: Python uses indentation in place of  `{}` structures in JS, so it needs to be precise. Try https://rextester.com/PYNCJY90704

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Nick you're totally right, it works fine with link you provided it But somehow on this playground, it doesn't https://trinket.io/python/2578572a61

Comment: That link has different indentation though.

Comment: @gilch ok, thanks! At least now, I know that it was an error in my code or logic. If you add answer, I'll accept it so you get your rep! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation is incorrect. Python's blocks begin with a `:`, but it needs a dedent to know when they end. An empty block must have an explicit `pass`.

In particular, note that this `if` has an empty block without a `pass`. (The next line was not indented more, so the block must have ended.)

```
if isinstance(x, str):
results.append(x)
```

And also, within a block, indentation must be consistent. The `for` is an unexpected indent, because there was no starting `:` to allow it to be indented more.

```
results = list()

    for x in arr:
```

Comment: consider providing the code that is correctly indented along with pointing out the lines where there is an error

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your issue is with the indentation in your if statement. If your goal is to obtain a filtered list of only strings from the original list, not just printing the list you could go with:

```
def filter_list(arr):
    results = list()

    for x in arr:
        if isinstance(x, str):
            results.append(x)
    return results
```

Another alternative would be to use a functional approach that is popular in python and probably familiar coming from javascript:

```
results = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), arr)
```

In the above, `results` will be an iterator as [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) function, a function for which the results can be iterated over. If you want to get back a list, you can add `list(results)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def filter_list(arr):

  results = list()

  for x in arr:
      if isinstance(x, str):
          results.append(x)
          print(results)

filter_list([1, 2, 3, "a", "b", 4])
```

Your spacing is incorrect. This code works.

Check if statement spacing. Particularly line 5 block.

- 1 tab indent on line 5
- 2 tab indents on line 6
- And 3 on line 7 and 8

Indents are typically 4 spaces, you can use literal tabs but note you cannot mix tabs and spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
def filter_list(arr):
    results = list()

    for x in arr:
        if isinstance(x, str):
            results.append(x)
        print(results)

filter_list([1, 2, 3, "a", "b", 4])
```

1) Make the indentaion same in line 2 and line 4.
2) indent result.append(x) after if statement.