# IndentationError: when running with conn.cursor

Tags: python, psql

I'm currently working with the book "SQL for Data Analytics" and I'm encountering an issue in when trying to run a line.

```
with psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", user="myuser[enter image description here][1]", password="mypassword", dbname="sqlda", port=5432) as conn:
```

```
with conn.cursor () as cur: cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 5")
```

I get an error in `with conn.cursor`. I'm attaching a picture if it helps to see what I'm supposed to do:

[image: 1]

Comment: In the screenshot you posted, the line `records = cut.fetchall()` has incorrect indentation.

Comment: Thank you! and how do I correct it? That is a screenshot from what I am supposed to write in my terminal.

Comment: See [the indicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)