# Why can't I add for loop within a block without occuring indentation error?

Tags: python

```
def PhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text) != 14:
        return False
    for i in range(0, 4):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    if text[4] != '-':
        return False
    for i in range(5, 8):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    if text[8] != '-':
         return False
    for i in range(9, 11):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    if text[11] != '-':
        
 ** for i in range(12, 14):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False **
    return True
```

Comment: why you typed "**" in your code? are you trying to make it comment?

Comment: What is the purpose of using `**` in your example?

Comment: Hello Mag, maybe you are mixing spaces and tabs in your code?

Comment: There's an indentation error because it isn't (as shown) indented.

Comment: Also, all those `for` loops can be replaced with `if not all(c.isdecimal() for c in text[0:4]): return False` and so on, or the _entire method_ can be replaced with checking a regular expression like `^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d[3}-\d{3}$`

Comment: Aside from the indentation error you get, this can be done in a single line using regex instead of `if`s and `for`s.

Comment: See [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45621722/3890632)

Comment: @errata I was clueless about how to highlight the piece of code I needed to fix so that's the reason why I applied stars**

Comment: @deadshot no, trying to highlight the piece of code I wanted to correct.

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot I checked and there's nothing to do with that, just needed to empty the if statement with [pass]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before the for loop you have the following:

```py
    # This if block is empty
    if text[11] != '-':
        
    for i in range(12, 14):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    return True
```

In python, empty code blocks have to use the `pass` keyword

So, just add an indented `pass` to the empty if statement

```py
    # That's better :)
    if text[11] != '-':
        pass
    for i in range(12, 14):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: If the `if` is intended to be empty, it can just be eliminated altogether. `pass` is usually used to ignore a case matched by an `elif` to eliminate falling through to an `else` clause.

Comment: sorry for my poor writing))) and thank you for the correction!

Comment: @Mag no problem as it's your first time, welcome to stack overflow! :)

Comment: @Mag For future questions make sure to learn proper formatting rules - you're more likely to get responses with a thoughtful, well-formatted question

Comment: @BryanC Thank you again! I'll follow your advice and get better)))