# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (Elif)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def gcd(a,b):
if b == 0:
    return a
elif a < b:
    return gcd(b,a)
else:
    return gcd(b,a%b)
```

I am new to python, i hope this has something to do with spaces.
Can anyone help me out.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26F4R.png)
Also attached the image. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error, it says `IndentationError`, so you have problem with the indentation. You should know that python depends on indentation to define the scope of each block, so the content of a function must be indented, otherwise it won't be considered as the content of the function.

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    elif a < b:
        return gcd(b,a)
    else:
        return gcd(b,a%b)
```

Comment: The error says `IndentationError` but the full message is not consistent with the code they have posted. It is clear that at whatever time they got that message, the `if` statement *was* indeed indented (or it would have complained about that), but the unindent on `elif` was to the wrong column. One can only speculate about exactly what their code did look like, although I've shown a possible example in my answer. I am guessing that the code which they finally posted was the result of a failed attempt to fix the original error.

Answer (score 0):

Function definitions also have a level of indentation to them, so it should look as follows:

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    elif a < b:
        return gcd(b,a)
    else:
        return gcd(b,a%b)
```

Comment: Got it i did that in the image attached to the question brother.