# Scope issue with nested functions

Tags: python, function, scope, nested

I get an unexpected indent error in `def calculte_interest_on_savings(savings)`? The variable savings got defined above on the exact same line...

```
def print_balance():
   balance = 1000
   print("Your balance is " + str(balance))

   def deduct(amount):
      print("Your new balance is " + str(balance -  amount))
      savings = balance-amount
 
   deduct(500)

      def calculte_interest_on_savings(savings):
        print("You will gain interest on: " + str     (savings))
    
      calculte_interest_on_savings(savings)     


print_balance()
```

Comment: The problem, assuming your code in the question is indented the same as the real code you’re running, is that `def calculte…` is indented below the line above which reads `deduct(500)` - it should be at the same level of indent as that line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: An unexpected indent is a syntax error, not a scope error. Although, it looks like scoping is also a problem in this code.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I would write this way

```py
def print_balance(balance):
    print("Your balance is " + str(balance))

def deduct(amount,balance):
    print("Your new balance is " + str(balance -  amount))
    savings = balance-amount
    return savings

def calculte_interest_on_savings(savings):
    print("You will gain interest on: " + str(savings))


balance = 1000
print_balance(balance)
savings=deduct(500,balance)
calculte_interest_on_savings(savings)
print_balance(balance)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to nest these functions.

```
def print_balance():
   balance = 1000
   print("Your balance is " + str(balance))
   savings = deduct(balance, 500)
   calculate_interest_on_savings(savings)  
  

def deduct(balance, amount):
    print("Your new balance is " + str(balance - amount))
    savings = balance - amount
    return savings
 

def calculate_interest_on_savings(savings):
    print("You will gain interest on: " + str(savings))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_balance()
```