# Simple changes of a particular code can make your code not working

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out why some simple changes can mess up a program in any programming language. It can get annoying and make you rage.

**Here is an example of a working code:**

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        print("New Person")

        
p = Person()

class Francis(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("My name is Francis")

        
f = Francis()
```

As you can see, it gave an expected result.

```
New Person
My name is Francis
```

But a slight change will trigger the system and make a program go wrong.

**For example:**

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        print("New Person")


p = Person()

class Francis(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__():
            print("My name is Francis")


f = Francis()
```

That small change already made the code faulty. The error is invalid syntax. Honestly, how is this possible? I'm honestly surprised to see that a small change makes a big difference in the world of programming (yes, including Python).

Comment: I think it's Python itself. The programming world is strictly based on code and honestly can ruin your day,

Comment: Why do you have a colon and then an indent after the call to super? It's not valid python syntax, you're not starting a new block

Comment: Sometimes while writing a program in Python, you might accidentally use invalid syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is? Syntax is fundamentally important in all languages, if your code is not syntactically correct then the compiler/interpreter will not be able to parse your code

Comment: Consider code as a DNA chain, imagine you randomly modify something in such a chain and its effects.

Comment: Indentation is important part of Python syntax. So change in indentation can make your code act differently or even raise an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it) Different error, but accepted answer is doing great jon at explaining why indentation matters in Python.

Answer (score 1):

At the highest level your question can be answered by saying every language has a syntax and that syntax must be followed in order for the language "to work". In Python whitespace, specifically the whitespace at the beginning of a line, is very important for the interpreter to determine what your code is supposed to do. In your example you provide an example of an [unexpected indent](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) and a misplaced colon. You have incorrectly signaled to the interpreter that a new code block should begin and thus an error is shown to you.

While Python is a very syntactically forgiving language compared to predecessors like COBOL or C it is important to remember that even still tiny variations in the way a block of code is written can lead to immense changes in the code's behavior. Consider these two code snippets:

```
x=0
while x<10:
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

and

```
x=0
while x<10:
    print(x)
x += 1
```

The first will print out the digits 0-9 while the second will remain stuck in an infinite loop all due to a simple indentation error. I recommend reading up on [Python's syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics).