# Pylint in Codio keeps telling me I have indentation errors, but there is no way to fix the indents without breaking my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, python-turtle, codio

I am trying to submit a turtle program in codio, but the autograder keeps telling me I am missing indentations in my function definition section. My program works perfectly in other IDE's like repl.it and VScode. Codio is basically saying that everything needs to be indented 1 more, but if I do that it will break.

Here is a section of my code. The indentation is the same throughout all of my functions:

```
def triangle(size):
    for _i in range(3):
    bby.forward(size)
    bby.rt(120)

def rectangle(size):
  for _i in range(2):
    bby.forward(size*2)
    bby.rt(90)
    bby.forward(size)
    bby.rt(90)
```

Comment: The two lines inside the `for` loop in `triangle` need to be indented more. That won't break anything.

Comment: Your question should be answered here: [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: There's no way this code works in any Python environment. The indentation error here is not specific to any Python interpreter or version. You may be copy-pasting the wrong thing, or running different code than you think in those other environments, possibly due to forgetting to save, or something like that.