# IndentationError: expected an indented block - Don't know where this comes from

Tags: python, syntax

I built this function and don't understand, why it doesn't work:

```
def give_age_of(birthday):

    import datetime
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

    aging = birthday
    totoday = datetime.date.today()
    age_of = relativedelta(totoday,aging).years

    return age_of
```

```
 File "<ipython-input-258-df8b9618ac1f>", line 5
    import datetime
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: There are no indentation errors in the code you posted. Make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: It is a bit suspicious that your line 5 is actually line 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @KlausD. I didn't copy some #comments if that is what you mean?

Comment: If you have a traceback with line number you should make sure they match.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I got it, thanks to KlausD. The code that actually doesn't work is the following, but I found the solution myself already. I had to dedent the comment in line 1.

```
    # blablabla

def give_age_of(birthday):

    import datetime 
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

    aging = birthday
    totoday = datetime.date.today()
    age_of = relativedelta(totoday,aging).years

    return age_of
```

Comment: This is wrong, and you must have done something else that accidentally fixed the problem. Lines that contain only a comment and/or whitespace do not have any special requirements and do not cause problems for other lines.