# What is wrong with my elif statement: invalid syntax?

Tags: python, windows, if-statement, syntax-error, computer-science

```
class Snake(object):

    def __init__(self, size):

        self.size = size

        self.board = []

        self.snake = []

        self.food = []

        self.score = 0

   def move(self, direction):

if direction in "UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT":

    self.board[self.snake[0]][self.snake[1]] = direction

    self.snake = self.snake[1:] + [self.snake[0]]



def eat(self, food):

if food == "right":

    self.score += 1

elif food == "left":

    self.score -= 1



def checkCollision(self, other):

if self.snake[0] == other.snake[0] and self.snake[1] == other.snake[1]:

    print("Oops, you hit yourself!")

elif self.snake[0] == other.snake[1] and other.snake[0] == self.snake[1]:

    print("Oops, you hit the wall!")

else:

    print("Collision")





if __name__ == "__main__":

    snake = Snake(5)

    print("You are playing as: " + snake.name)

while snake.score >= 0:

    print("You have " + snake.score + " points left.")

    print("moving snake")

    snake.move("left")

    print("Current board:")

    print(snake.board)

    print("Eating food")

    snake.eat("left")

    print("Current board:")

    print(snake.board)
```

The Problem is with line 37
elif food == "left":

I'm getting a syntax error: invalid syntax and I am not sure how to go about fixing this specific error. I am new to programming in python and this should probably be obvious to someone more experienced I am hoping. For me I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: spacing is important.  copy paste looks like it made the issue worse.  look into formatting the code.

Comment: Your code is improperly formatted. It's impossible to tell what's a copy-paste error and what's an actual indentation error.

Comment: You've got to indent your code. There is no indentation for the `eat` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python relies on indentation for its blocks. Multiple of your lines aren't indented properly.

```
if food == "right":
    self.score += 1
elif food == "left":
    self.score -= 1
```

Make sure to indent your code. There are other parts of the code that aren't indented properly such as `checkCollision` and your `if __name__ == "__main__"`

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation problem with your code. You can find out more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45621723/17556172).

Comment: This has been solved thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should just add tabulation in elif food == "left"
when using il and elif use it in this way (**if and elif in the same degree of space**)

```
if condition:
     do something
elif condition:
     do something
```