# What is this Indentation Error in this following code

Tags: python

[image: ghfgfghhggkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk]What is this Indentation Error in this following code

```
#We first import the datetime module
import datetime
while True:
try:
birthday = input("Enter your Date of Birth(eg. December 25 2005):")
birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(birth_day, '%B %d %Y')
break
except:
print("Please put in the Format 'Month Day Year' without any initial space")
tday = datetime.datetime.today()
delta = (tday - birthday).total_seconds()
print("You are",delta,"seconds old")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "try"     then you should give indent like this

```
#We first import the datetime module
import datetime
while True:
    try:
        birthday = input("Enter your Date of Birth(eg. December 25 2005):")
        birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(birth_day, '%B %d %Y')
        break
    except:
        print("Please put in the Format 'Month Day Year' without any initial space")
tday = datetime.datetime.today()
delta = (tday - birthday).total_seconds()
print("You are",delta,"seconds old")
```

And python usually use 4 white space for indent

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

while True:
    try:
        birthday = input("Enter your Date of Birth(eg. December 25 2005):")
        birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(birth_day, '%B %d %Y')
        break
    except:
        print("Please put in the Format 'Month Day Year' without any initial space")

tday = datetime.datetime.today()
delta = (tday - birthday).total_seconds()
print("You are",delta,"seconds old")
```