# How to prevent this type of error in python?

Tags: python, syntax

So I was writing the code for the event handler and I took care of the syntax but I am getting an error

**The code I wrote:**

```
#game loop
run = True
while run:

    #event handler
    for event in pg.event.get():
    #quit program
    **if event.type == pg.QUIT:
    run = False**
pg.quit()
```

**The error I get**

- Expected indented block on the lines I marked bold

Comment: Means just that, your indentation is wrong.

Comment: Your indentation is, indeed, wrong.  A `for` loop must be followed by at least one indented line underneath it.  And an `if` statement must also be followed by a line indented underneath it.  Your code doesn't have either of those.

Comment: `indetations` are very important in Python but you start all lines in the same column. Maybe see indentations in some examples/tutorials for `pygame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentations are very important in Python but you start all lines in the same column.

Here is an example with correct indentations:

```
run = True
while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():    #  4 spaces
        #quit program               #  8 spaces
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:   #  8 spaces
            run = False             # 12 spaces
pg.quit()
```

Frankly, you should see correct indentations in every examples/tutorials for `pygame`.

---

**EDIT:**

If you see the same indentations in your code then maybe you mix spaces and tabs - but many editors and IDEs have functions to convert tabs to 4 spaces. They can even do it automatically. If your editor doesn't have this feature then you have to control it on your own.

Comment: You should know that this is a very common FAQ and thus is likely to have a canonical; and that answering simple beginner questions is prone to leave them up on the site longer before the [roomba](/help/roomba) can delete them. If you cannot be bothered to find the canonical, please at least abstain from answering.

Comment: For the record, the canon I have bookmarked (i.e. I don't know if it's "official" or if  there could be a better one still) is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-or-a-taberror-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: thank you for the link. I know that this is common problem and maybe I shouldn't answer it but I also know that beginners often doesn't search answers for problems. If I would know this link then I would add this as comment. (but frankly, I also didn't try to find other answer ;) but I will add this link to my resources)

Comment: Here, though, we are talking about a 100k+ veteran user of this site since 11 years.